# Cant Boot into linux if Wifi card is inserted at same time as m.2

Tags: wifi, hard-disk

Unfortunately I cant provide a system configuration as I currently cannot log into my linux mint desktop. I am running linux mint 20 i9-9900 GT710 for display output and GTX1070 for computations.

The problem began when I installed a new Western Digital Sn750 m.2 drive and a new Gigabyte WiFi card. I have dual boot enabled through my GRUB and I was able to boot into windows without any issues (so hardware isnt an issue?). However, when I try to log into linux mint I get a black screen with a blinking cursor. If I take out the WiFi card and leave in the m.2 Drive I can boot into linux normally. Likewise, if I remove the m.2 drive and leave in the wifi card I boot into linux normally.

At this point I am going to remove the WiFi card and run a temporary ethernet cable to my room.

In summary:
-Windows works fine after installing new WiFi card and m.2 drive

-Linux mint works if I remove the WiFi card neither old nor new wifi card work if m.2 drive is inserted.

-Linux mint works if I remove the m.2 Drive and use new WiFi card. Presumably works with old WiFi card as this was the initial configuration

I appreciate any help.

EDIT: it has occurred to me that I may be using too many pcie lanes
Z390 chipset supports 24, but I am using
GTX1070 x16
GT710   x4
wifi    x1
m.2     x4

This gives me 25 lanes. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Which motherboard do you have?

Comment: @glibg10b. its a Gigabyte Z390 Gaming M. Some of the issues were explained by reading the motherboard manual. One of the m.2 slots disables SATA0, which had my linux boot. However, the other slot does not. After trying all sorts of combinations I decided to return the m.2 drive and I bought a SATA SSD to use for scratch. Thanks